# Calculate length of service of an employee in Years, Months and Days using T-SQL when there is a gap in service?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to calculate length of service of an Employee when there is a gap in his tenure. I have a period1 from '08/09/2003' to '06/25/2009', period 2 is from '06/10/2015' to '03/31/2022' or GETDATE(). can someone explain me how can I calculate the whole period(Length of service) when there is a gap like this for that Employee ?

All dates above are in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format.

So, the Period1 service is - 5 Years, 10 Months, 16 Days
Period2 service is - 6 Years, 9 Months, 21 Days
The requirements is
total service should be - 12 Years, 8 Months, 7 Days

I know to calculate one period length but having issues while I try to calculate length when there is a gap

Comment: *"All dates above are in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format."* Date and time data types don't have a "format", if you *are* storing date (and time) data with a format, then it by definition *isn't* a `date`, but something like a `varchar`; a fatal and fundamental flaw in your application.

Comment: Honestly, with dates like this, X months doesn't make sense. For a single continuous period, perhaps, but a month can be between 28 and 31 days long. If there are breaks in that period, "months" doesn't make sense any more, as you don't know what period of time a month is anymore.

Comment: If you can calculate the value for a single row, then it is a trivial matter to sum the datediff value from multiple rows and apply your calculation to that sum.

Comment: How did you get 9 months and 21 days difference for the second period ?

Comment: And how do you expect to sum the days ? You say that 16 + 21 days = 1 month and 7 days, but is that based on a month of 31, 30, 29 or 28 days ? How can you know ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611669/guidog its not about 16+21 days = 1 month 7 days, its about calculate length of service when there are two intervals of period ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate the years, months and days for each period and then sum them, because you don't know how to sum the days (31, 30, 29 or 28)

So, maybe if we do sum up all these values, and then add them to the enddate of the first period then we can calculate the values from the startdate and this extended endate ?

The outcome will never be exact, because of the difference in months length, but this maybe is as close that you can get

I tested it in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35956b83d4488cb9b17f52a68fe21ed7)

But, I don't get your expected result because I still don't see how you get 9 months and 21 days from your second period.

Take a look at the dBFiddle, if it is not what you are looking for then maybe it helps inspire you in the right direction

```
select t2.period,
       t2.startdate,
       t2.enddate,
       
       datediff(month, t2.startdate, t2.enddate) / 12 as years,
       datediff(month, t2.startdate, t2.enddate) - ((datediff(month, t2.startdate, t2.enddate) / 12) * 12) as months,
       datediff(day, 
                datefromparts(2022, datepart(month, t2.enddate), datepart(day, t2.startdate)),
                datefromparts(2022, datepart(month, t2.enddate), datepart(day, t2.enddate))
     ) as days
       
       
from   (select temp.period,
               min(temp.startdate) as startdate,
               dateadd(day, sum(temp.days), dateadd(month, sum(temp.months), dateadd(year, sum(temp.years), min(temp.startdate)))) as enddate
        from   ( select t.period,
                        t.startdate,
                        t.enddate,
                        datediff(month, t.startdate, t.enddate) / 12 as years,
                        datediff(month, t.startdate, t.enddate) - ((datediff(month, t.startdate, t.enddate) / 12) * 12) as months,
                        datediff(day, 
                                 datefromparts(2022, datepart(month, t.enddate), datepart(day, t.startdate)),
                                 datefromparts(2022, datepart(month, t.enddate), datepart(day, t.enddate))
                       ) as days
                 from   table1 t
              ) temp
        group by temp.period
      ) t2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611669/guidog Actually the dates are in MM/DD/YYYY format. 06/10/2015 means June 10th, but you have taken it as October 6th

Comment: @AnandM OK if I switch that date then my outcome is exact as you requested

Comment: @AnandM I altered the DBFiddle so it matches this date

Answer (score 0):

This soluction works pretty good. Although, counting days this way is kind off weird. If you start work at June 22nd and end July 22nd, have you then worked 1 month? or 30 days?

```
DECLARE @ServiceTbl TABLE (StartDate Date, EndDate Date)
DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate date
DECLARE @Sum TABLE (Years int, months int, days int)

INSERT INTO @ServiceTbl 
SELECT '08/09/2003', '06/25/2009'
UNION SELECT '06/10/2015', null    

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY FOR
  SELECT StartDate, ISNULL(EndDate, GetDate())
  FROM @ServiceTbl
OPEN cur
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @StartDate, @EndDate
    if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 break

  ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        0 as countYear
      , 0 as countMonth
      , DATEDIFF(Day, @StartDate, EOMONTH(@StartDate, 0)) as CountDays

      , EOMONTH(@StartDate, 1) as nextDate
      , @EndDate as EndDate
      , 0 as id
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        CASE 
          WHEN nextDate < EndDate 
          AND countMonth + 1 = 12 
            THEN countYear + 1
          ELSE countYear END
      , CASE 
          WHEN nextDate < EndDate 
          AND countMonth + 1 < 12
            THEN countMonth + 1

          WHEN nextDate < EndDate
            THEN 0
          ELSE countMonth END

      , CountDays + CASE 
          WHEN EndDate < EOMONTH(nextDate, 1) 
            THEN DATEDIFF(day, nextDate, EndDate)
          ELSE 0 END
    
      , EOMONTH(nextDate, 1)
      , EndDate
      , id + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE nextDate < EndDate
  )
    INSERT INTO @Sum
    SELECT TOP 1 countYear, countMonth, CountDays
    FROM CTE
    ORDER BY id Desc

END
CLOSE cur DEALLOCATE cur
   


SELECT SUM(Years) + FLOOR((SUM(months) + FLOOR(SUM(Days) / 31)) / 12) as Years
  , (SUM(months) + FLOOR(SUM(Days) / 31)) % 11 as Months
  , SUM(days) % 30 as Days
FROM @Sum
```

Comment: why this weird loop construct (endless loop and jump out anyway), why not a simple `while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` ?

Comment: And what do you do with months that have less than 31 days ? I also wonder how bad this will perform

Comment: What do you mean? EOMONTH(@StartDate, 0)) Handles the amount of days per month, not always 31. 
The error might occur at the sum at the end, but that's because I'm not convinced of how to calculate overlapping months. If you started June 22nd and end November 22nd, Have you then worked for 5 months? What if you start the 22nd in July and end December 22, is it 5 months or 4 months and 30 days? 

And a Recursive CTE is more efficient than a cursor if that's what you're refering to.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the sum at the end, it will be impossible to get an exact amount off days no matter what solution. But about performance, you do use a cursor which I always try very hard to avoid because of bad performance. But all things being said, there is no optimal 100% correct solution for this problem imho

Comment: Agreed, I always try to avoid cursors as well. 
I just didn't know how to loop over the periods otherwise. And i didn't want to put too much time into it either :)